# Play framework and Java version

Tags: java, playframework, java-8, playframework-2.2

I would like to know if there is any connection between the play framework version (of my java app) to the java version of my app?

Example: if I use play 2.2.1 and has java8 on my computer. Can I use java8 stuff in my code?

If there is a connection. What is the first play version that works with java8?

Thank you
Niv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play 2.3.x is first version that mentions Java 8, [see here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23#Java-8)

Today morning I was talking with colleague of mine who found running 2.1.x some kind of problematic with Java 8, fortunately for him - he can run his project with lower Java.

I'm afraid, that you can meet some problems with 2.2.x as well, the good option is to create small projects and test the Java 8 features against 2.2.1, or better - rise the app's Play version to 2.3.x, here's the [migration tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23)

Answer (score 0):

I've also notice on play 2.3.7 that it has some problems with recognise static methods in interfaces